# Can I do a NATURAL JOIN is Slick v2?

Tags: sql, scala, join, slick, relational-algebra

The title is self-explanatory.  Using 2.0.0-M3, I'd like to avoid unnecessary verbosity is the form of explicitly naming the columns to be joined on, since they are appropriately named, and since `NATURAL JOIN` is part of the SQL standard.  Not to mention, Wikipedia itself even says that ["The natural join is arguably one of the most important operators since it is the relational counterpart of logical AND."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_join#Natural_join)

I think the foregoing ought to be clear enough, but just if not, read on.  Suppose I want to know the supplier-name and part-number of each part.  Assuming appropriate case classes not shown:

```
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[Supplier](tag, "suppliers") {
  def snum  = column[String]("snum")
  def sname = column[String]("sname")
  def * = (snum, sname) <> (Supplier.tupled, Supplier.unapply _)
}

class Shipments(tag: Tag) extends Table[Shipment](tag, "shipments") {
  def snum  = column[String]("snum")
  def pnum = column[String]("pnum")
  def * = (snum, pnum) <> (Shipment.tupled, Shipment.unapply _)
}

val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers]
val shipments = TableQuery[Shipments]
```

Given that both tables have the `snum` column I want to join on, seems as if

```
( suppliers join shipments ).run
```

ought to return a Vector with my desired data, but I get a failed attempt at an `INNER JOIN`, failing (at run-time) since it's missing any join condition.

I know I can do

```
suppliers.flatMap( s => shipments filter (sp => sp.snum === s.snum) map (sp => (s.sname, sp.pnum)) )
```

but, even without the names of all the columns I omitted for clarity of this question, it's still quite a lot more typing (and proofreading) than simply

```
suppliers join shipments
```

or, for that matter

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers NATURAL JOIN shipments;
```

If the Scala code is messier than the SQL code, then I really start questioning things.  Is there no way simply to do a natural join in Slick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not supported by Slick. Please submit a ticket or pull request.

To improve readability of query code, you can put your join conditions into re-usable values. Or you can put the whole join in a function or method extension of Query[Suppliers,Supplier].

Alternatively you could look at the AutoJoin pattern (which basically makes your join conditions implicit) described here http://slick.typesafe.com/docs/#20130612_slick_vs_orm_scaladays_2013 and implemented here https://github.com/cvogt/play-slick/blob/scaladays2013/samples/computer-database/app/util/autojoin.scala